# moduli space of meromorphic $G$-Higgs bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, integrable-systems

I want to clarify with some topics in moduli space of semistable $G$-Higgs bundles on curve $X$ (genus $g$ is large enough) of fixing topological type $d \in \pi_1(G)$. Simpson's construction gives us the dimension formula for the case when an element $[(P,\varphi)]$ ($P$ -- is a  principal bundle on $X$) of the moduli space $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\varphi \in \mathrm{ad}P\otimes K_X$:
$$
\mathrm{dim}\, \mathcal M = 2(g-1)\,\mathrm{dim}\,G.
$$

Let us consider the effective reduced divisor $D$ on $ X$. Is it true that dimension of $\mathcal{M}_D$ (moduli space of semistable pairs $[(P,\varphi)]$ where $\varphi \in \mathrm{ad}P\otimes K_X(D)$) takes the form 
$$
\mathrm{dim}\, \mathcal M = 2(g-1)\,\mathrm{dim}\,G + \delta \, \mathrm{dim}G, 
$$
$\delta$ -- degree of divisor.

I will be appreciated for any references.

Comment: In the case $G=GL(n)$ you'll find a detailed study of the moduli space, including the formula you mention for the dimension, in [this paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASENS/ASENS_1995_4_28_4/ASENS_1995_4_28_4_391_0/ASENS_1995_4_28_4_391_0.pdf) of Bottacin, 3.1. It should not be hard to extend the proof to arbitrary $G$.

Comment: It should be straightforward to calculate the index of the linearized Cauchy-Riemann operator on punctured Riemann surface with some properly chosen weighted Sobolev norm. I guess your formula should be correct.